# Word: Floating object beneath anchored paragraph

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

writing my thesis with word I miss Latex. I'm struggling with the layout options of objects, e.g. a figure/group/table. I want to have them located beneath a certain (anchored) paragraph in the text without surrounding text. It doesn’t matter how far away from the anchored paragraph as long as it stays beneath the anchor. It should not split up paragraphs (however in general paragraphs should be splitable in the document, e.g. at the end of a page). Furthermore, if it’s a big picture which has to be located on the next page text should "move" on the black spot, or the picture should move downwards in text. Do you understand what I want to achieve?

Thus I selected wrapping style "Top and bottom". Furthermore, I selected in "position" "vertical" "absolute position" "1cm" below "paragraph". Then the paragraph gets split up after the first line and the picture always stays close to the anchored paragraph, not "moving downwards" in the text.

How can I achieve what I want?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your explanation then I suggest you do not use the wrapping text option on the image. Instead, put the image "inline" with text and place it on its own paragraph.

If you want to always keep the paragraph and the text together and not allow them to split across pages, you should use the "Keep with next" option, which is located on the format paragraph dialog.

[image]